# Java JPA how relate an entity instance with all instances of another entity?

Tags: java, jpa, entity, h2, one-to-many

I work with an embedded H2 database in which I use the @OneToMany relationship to relate an entity instance (product) to multiple instances of the other entities (suppliers); it's useful when I have specific suppliers for a particular product.
However now, I want to associate all the suppliers with every single product; I don't want to generate in my supplier table different supplier records for each product, instead I want to have only 5 records (5 suppliers) in my supplier table which are associated to every single product, it few words I want to achieve something like "one to all", is it possible to do it using JPA annotations?

Product entity

```
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    private String productCode;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "supplier_id", referencedColumnName = "productCode")
    private List<Supplier> suppliers;

}
```

Supplier entity

```
@Entity
public class Supplier {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    private String name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Unidirectional `@OneToMany` association:**

```
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    // @Column(name = "id") maybe
    // @GeneratedValue maybe
    private String productCode;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true) // according to your need
    private List<Supplier> suppliers;

    ...
}
```

And,

```
@Entity
public class Supplier {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    ...
}
```

**`@ManyToOne` association:**

```
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    // @Column(name = "id") maybe
    // @GeneratedValue maybe
    private String productCode;

    ...
}
```

And,

```
@Entity
public class Supplier {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "PRODUCT_ID_FK"))
    private Product product;

    private String name;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you @MinarMahmud, trying with the unidirectional association, I got the error "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.personal.model.Supplier", meanwhile if I remove CascadeType.ALL I got "org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["PUBLIC.UK_EWOOML1PFBM1FXBCMR7BC9JN0_INDEX_F ON PUBLIC.STUDY_SOURCESYSTEM(SOURCESYSTEMS_ID) VALUES 1"; SQL statement:" (Study is Product and Supplier is SourceSystem in my real application).

Comment: @JeromeTech You are welcome. You can also use bidirectional `@OneToMany`. I have mentioned only the unidirectional ones. And also feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem!

Comment: ManyToOne association (your second suggestion) doesn't fit with my necessities because at some point I just pull all from "Product" entity (findAll()) and I got all data from there.

Comment: For the detach entity exception, i need to see the service/dao layer code.

Comment: For the SQL exception, why is there a table named `STUDY_SOURCESYSTEM`? These types of tables are used as join tables in `@ManyToMany` associations.
Did you change your DB schema according to your new entity mappings?

Comment: The tricky part is that I use the same data model (entities) to populate and store the Product in H2 database (instance by instance), then I use findAll() on the ProductRepository to pull the Product with all the enriched data (Product contains many, many, many attributes)

Comment: But that shouldn't need a join table. Yours is a regular use case.

Comment: Replying to the SQL exception question, I use my entities to create an embedded H2 database, so the DB schema is in function to my entity model.